# Laravel Aws S3 Link

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have created the aws account and linked it on my laravel, the images are storing inside aws and also in my database.

but i do not want to use aws url but my own website url to access the image like so `localhost:8000/images/uploads/image.jpg`

```
      private function storeImage($post)
    {
        if (request()->hasFile('image')){

            $original = request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $post->update([
                'image' => request()->file('image')->storeAs('uploads', $original),
            ]);

            $image = Image::make(request()->file('image'));
            Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads', $image->stream(), 'public');
            $image = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl("uploads", Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
            $image = 'http://localhost:8000/images/';
        }
    }
```

I want this image link to change from the one below

```
@if($post->image)
        <img class="post-image rectangle" src="{{ secure_asset('https://example-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/' . $post->image ) }}">
        @endif
```

to something like this

```
@if($post->image)
    <img class="post-image rectangle" src="{{ secure_asset('images/' . $post->image ) }}">
@endif
```

which displays an image link like this `http://localhost:8000/images/uploads/image.jpg`

mind you image is stored in my database like `uploads/image.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

You're storing it in a S3 bucket that's why it should be linked to the buckets domain. If you want to use your own domain, better off store it inside your site or better [setup a custom domain for your S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs).